# How to populate Bootstrap table with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I've created a table using Bootstrap. When I do my network call the table is not populating.

I'm not sure if it's the way I am trying to populate it or the JSON object being returned or a combination of the two.

When I inspect the page, the get request returns 200. So the object is coming back but the table remains empty and doesn't show any content from the JSON object in the table.

This is my full code in the index.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Table V01</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <script src="vendor/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.ico"/>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animate/animate.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--===============================================================================================-->

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.12.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.12.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified Locales -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.12.1/locale/bootstrap-table-zh-CN.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-table100">
            <div class="wrap-table100">
                <div class="table100">
                    <div class="col col-xs-6 text-right">
                        <button class="button-create">
                            <span>New Card +</span>
                        </button>
          </div>
                    <table id="cardTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="table100-head">
                                <th class="column1">Business Name</th>
                                <th class="column2">Card Offer</th>
                                <th class="column3">Active</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script language="javascript">


self.cardsTable = $('#cardTable').bootstrapTable(
{
    "columnDefs": [
        {"className": "dt-center", "targets": "4"}
    ],
    "autoWidth": false,
    ajax: {
        "url": "http://MY.IP.AD.DRESS/cards",
        "cache": true
    },
    columns: [
        { data: null, 'orderable': false,
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        var cards = 'card';
                        return cards['businessName'];

            }
        },
        { data: null, 'orderable': false,
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        var cards = 'card';
                        return cards['businessName'];

            }
        },
        { data: null, 'orderable': false,
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        var cards = 'card';
                        return cards['businessName'];

            }
        }
    ],
    "order": [[ 2, 'desc' ]]
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just so you guys understand a little better. This is how the JSON object gets returned: -

```
{
    "data": {
        "card": [
            {
                "_id": “179”,
                "businessName": “Business 1”
    },
{
                "_id": “180”,
                "businessName": "Business 2”
    },
{
                "_id": “181”,
                "businessName": "Business 3”
    }]
    }
}
```

Comment: What issues are you having? In order for us to assist you, please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So the issue is that the table is not populating at all. When I inspect the page, the get request returns 200. So the object is coming back but he table remains empty and doesn't show any content from the JSON object in the table.

Comment: There are different types of double quotes in your JSON. They are probably the cause. You always want to use the straight double quotes, the curly ones are for editorial purposes, not coding.